# Alternatives to JQuery.load() due to rangeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'll preface this with the fact that I fully understand the source of the "maximum calls exceeded" error- I'm trying to load a page that's just too big.  It's not an infinite recursion or a mistake.  I'm using JQuery.load() to dynamically load pages into a div (like an iFrame, but I want everything that gets loaded in to be able to see the parent's variables, functions, and css) for navigation.  One of the pages creates a table based on an SQL database, and every once in a while, that database might end up containing tens of thousands of records (nothing I can do about that; I'm not the one making the database).

So, without using iFrames, and without using JQuery, how can I go about loading the source of an external file into a div?  If I try using an XMLHTTP request, I imagine I'll get the exact same sort of error, because I'm trying to pull in too much data at once.  I'd be willing to deal with the slowdown of reading it in line by line and writing it to the page, but I don't know a good way of doing this without causing all sorts of issues because closing tags haven't been loaded yet.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this before?  Any suggestions?

Comment: your problem is not with jQuery load() its with a page with 10,000+ rows of data.  That needs to be resolved.  You should probably to ask for an api to select the nuber of rows you want returned then build a table based on that , or some type of communication with the service that is returning db results.  otherwise you might have to in your own javascript parse out all of that data except maybe the first 100

Comment: data on demand is so easy to acheive these days. Size of your database is irrelevant but dumping it all at once makes no sense..especialy if you are putting it all straight into html

Comment: also if you want to disreguard all of that , try a post instead of get for request and it can respond with a lot more data

Comment: May be "lazy loading" solves your problem?

Comment: As Scrott and charlietl pointed, try appending the records on smaller chunks using paging or loading content on scroll,... see also http://davidwalsh.name/documentfragment

Comment: I often find this tool - http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/  very useful when trying to optimize the dom size.